# Override method in inherited interface with subtype with generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overriding

I have the following hierarchy in java:

```
interface ObserverA {}

interface A {
  void method1();
  addObserver(Observer o);
}
```

And I want to extend it like this:

```
interface ObserverB extends ObserverA{}

interface B extends A {
   void method2();
   addObserver(ObserverB  o);
}
```

in such a way that the `addObserver()` method of `B` would override the same method in `A`.
As it is it doesn't work, implementations of `B` would need to implement both versions of `addObserver()`, I wan't to have just one.

Can this be done in a clever way that doesn't involve having to parameterize `A` like:

```
interface A<O extends Observer> { 
    addObserver(O o);
}
```

Hackish solutions are most welcome!

Comment: Generic type is always a better way for doing such thing where you dont know the type

Answer (score 4):

You can't narrow method parameter types in subinterfaces or subclasses. You can only broaden them, since implementations of the subtype must be able to fulfill the contract of the supertype.

Similarly, you can narrow return types and exceptions, but not broaden them, for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Although your example shows something different I suppose you would like to achive a generic interface implemented by different classes. Have a look at this:

```java
public interface Observer<T> {
    void addObserver(T t);
}

public class First implements Observer<First> {
    @Override
    public void addObserver(First t) {
    }
}

public class Second implements Observer<Second> {
    @Override
    public void addObserver(Second t) {
    }
}
```

As you can see both First and Second classes implement the same interface but with different types of parameters. They parametrize the implemented interface with themselved, but instead of writing `Observer<Frist>` you could write `Observer<Integer>` or whatever you would like.

**EDIT**

Taking into account your clarifications this would be a generic implementation of your code within the interface hierarchy you presented.

```java
interface ObserverA {}

interface A<T> {
    void method1();
    void addObserver(T o);
}

interface ObserverB extends ObserverA {}

interface B extends A<ObserverB> {
    void method2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about -

```
interface ObserverA {}

interface A {

    <T extends ObserverA> void addObserver(T o);
}
```

and -

```
interface ObserverB extends ObserverA{}

interface B extends A{

    // do nothing, or omit this interface entirely.

}
```

so that you'll be able to pass any type that inherits `ObserverA` as argument to the `addObserver` method.

If you are looking for a little explanation, then read on.

I have changed the method in the first interface to use [Bounded Type Parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). The way it's declared, it will allow any objects to be passed as argument to the `addObserver` method as long as it's type is `ObserverA`, or it inherits from `ObserverA`. Since your `ObserverB` is inheriting from `ObserverA`, you can safely pass objects of both `ObserverA` and `ObserverB` types to this method as argument.

**EDIT**

From your clarification, it seems that you should create two different interfaces without any hierarchical relationship between them. They seem to be unrelated because you want to provide implementations for only the second method, while avoiding the first one. So, rather than forcing yourself to provide the implementation for the method from the first interface, you should separate them. There is also an OOP principle for this - [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: I tried that already, the problem is that `B` would accept any `<O extends ObserverA>` and I want it to only accept `ObserverB` ( or `<O extends ObserverB>` for that matter)

Comment: The example I gave is a simplified version of what I want to do. `A` would be a more complex interface that `B` needs to extend, but its observers are also more complex than the ones from `A`. I edited the question to reflect the fact that 'B' extends functionality from 'A'

Comment: @Chirlo: I'd still say to avoid this design. If you need to use functionality from `ObjectA`, use delegation from the implementations of `ObjectB` to achieve that.