# php oop - force static method's param to be object of current class

Tags: php, oop

I want to do something like this:

```
class myclass{

   public static function(__class__ $param){
    // do somthing
   }
}
```

but `__class__` and `self::class` and nor `static` is not working.

how should I do this

Comment: Just by typing your classname like `public static function(myClass $param){`

Comment: `public static function(myclass $param)`?

Comment: you know the class name.. just use `myclass $param`... it will work even for abstract classes

Comment: No but, guys, suppose the class is extended tho, he might want to make sure the call to this method uses the child class, not the parent

Comment: I don't think type hinting supports `self` or `static` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: So I invite you to read this article and use Interfaces : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle .

Comment: actually what @Sebas said is true. I know I can just use the class name but I want to make it a little bit flexible and I just tested self keyword and it worked but is it return current class name or current abstract name?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `self`:

```
class A 
{
    public function foo(self $arg)
    {
        var_dump($arg);
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo($a); // object(A)#1 (0) { }
```

> No but, guys, suppose the class is extended tho, he might want to make sure the call to this method uses the child class, not the parent

You *can* manually restrict this contract for child classes, as shown in other anwsers (`instanceof`, etc), but it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

A subclass should **always** satisfy the contract of the superclass. In good design you should not to narrow the type of arguments in overridden methods.

Widening is allowed: [Contravariant method argument type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type) and PHP 7.2 partially [supports](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/parameter-no-type-variance) it.

Comment: you are absolutely right about the Liskov Principle. However I have found myself that for commodity sake this feature turned useful. Of course it was not invovled in any critical part of the design. Anyway, in an object scope, I use \ReflectionCass from inside the methods to get the real child class name when there's a child/parent extension.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enforce this dynamically for subclasses, I'm afraid that's not possible. The best you can do in this case is something like this:

```
class myclass {
    public static function doStuff(self $a) {
        if (!$a instanceof static) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('First argument must be of type %s', static::class));
        }
        // Do things with $a
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking does not make that much sense in strongly typed languages so I don't think it is something you can do in PHP.

Consider this:

```
abstract class A {
     public abstract function a(A $myTypeObject);
}

class B extends A { 
     public function a(B $myTypeObject) {
         return $this;
     }
}
```

Now the problem with this code is that it cannot exist because the overridden function must match the same signature as the parent function. In strongly typed languages `a` would in fact be an overload so `B` would have 2 declarations of `a` , one which accepts `A` and one which accepts `B`. However in PHP you'll just get a parse error. If you really want to enforce things you need runtime checking:

```
abstract class A {
     public function a($myTypeObject) {
          if (!($myTypeObject instanceof static)) {
              throw new \Exception("Invalid type");
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Strognly typed languages are disallow this too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15764663/1220930

Comment: @Timurib actually if you read the question, the problem the OP had there is that he got 2 methods when he just wanted 1 to override the parent one (which is what I am also saying here). He says *As it is it doesn't work, implementations of B would need to implement both versions of addObserver()*

Comment: Sorry, maybe i misunderstood where 2 methods there. I'm just want to warn about LSP violation. Imo, type hints in the PHP works well and usually they are enougth for type contracts. Manual type checking (instanceof, reflection, etc) smells bad in most cases.

Comment: @Timurib LSP is a tricky topic for weakly typed languages. Some would argue that it's not compatible with being type agnostic.

Comment: Why? At least in the strictly typed languages this principle maybe violated in same manner through downcasting. In the PHP we can do it easier, but this does not make the LSP and other practices inapplicable. Of course, every solution depends on context.